# Access a field with . in name in scripted fields kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a field that is getting pushed to Elastic and displayed on Kibana using Filebeat and ELK stack.

Field name is something like this: "field.name", i.e. it contains . in the name.

I created a Scripted field with the following code snippet:

```
if(doc['field.name.keyword'])
  return 1;
return 2;
```

But I always get an empty array in the result. After I create this scripted field by converting it to a number as it is of type string, I want to perform metric aggregation on it.

Does anybody have any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you also post your index mapping?

Comment: Sorry. I can't. Thanks btw.

Comment: Even by anonymizing the field names? If `field` of `nested` type?